# Using gspread with OAuth2 SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

Tags: python, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gspread

I am trying to access my google Spreadsheet using oauth2 using the gspread Python Library.I am new to Oauth2 and understand its benefits.But I am unable to use it.So far I have visited https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and generated CLIENT ID,SECRET and REDIRECT URI.

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials('developer@example.com', SIGNED_KEY, scope)
```

According to the Gspread [Docs](http://burnash.github.io/gspread/oauth2.html) I will need a SIGNED_KEY object.How do I get that?

An example will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In the developer console, (https://console.developers.google.com) go to APIs & auth > Credentials and click Create new Client ID, then choose Service Account. Your browser should download a .p12 file. Now convert it to a PEM for GAE by doing this in the command line:

```
openssl pkcs12 -passin pass:notasecret -in privatekey.p12 -nocerts -passout pass:notasecret -out key.pem
openssl pkcs8 -nocrypt -in key.pem -passin pass:notasecret -topk8 -out privatekey.pem
```

You then have to move the PEM to your app directory, open it in your app code and then use it as the second arg in `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials`

Also make sure the `app.yaml` libraries section includes `pycrypto`

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
```

I got this from someone's very helpful [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/vircheck/6292176)

Comment: Do I need to register an app engine application for this?I am not planning to port this application to GAE. This will be running in my personal computer.

Comment: In the dev console, it looks like you at least need to create a new project, and then create a service account/activate the APIs you're looking to use. I don't know if there's another way to get a .p12 file from Google except by creating a Service account.

Comment: Just tried this and seems like Google returns a json file with the credentials now by default...however, once the client id is created, a button to download a .p12 file appears